# How many parallel request can Python Flask process using Gunicorn?

Tags: python, flask, parallel-processing, jmeter, gunicorn

Can you please check if I am missing anything in the config?

I am running a python flask app using Gunicorn.

Our current flow of events is:

- Jmeter will trigger 8-10 jobs in parallel and send them to the AWS load balancer
- A requests then goes through an Nginix proxy and is forwarded to a Gunicorn/Flask app running on EC2 instance.

I am using the following configurations to enable multi-processing on Gunicorn/Flask, but these commands are not having any effect, as I see the jobs are being executed serially and not in parallel.
  
Please help me understand what I need to change in order to have all of these jobs execute in parallel.
 
Here is the list of the commands I have tried out but nothing has been working:

These commands are sync commands which I tried:

1. `gunicorn app1:application -b localhost:8000 --timeout 90000 -w 17`
2. `gunicorn app1:application -b localhost:8000 --timeout 90000 -w 17 --threads 2`
3. `gunicorn app1:application -b localhost:8000 --timeout 90000 -w 17 --threads 2 max_requests_jitter 4`
4. `gunicorn app1:application -b localhost:8000 --timeout 90000 -w 17 --max-requests 4`

These command are async commands which I tried:

5. `gunicorn app1:application -b localhost:8000 --timeout 90000 -w 17 --worker-class tornado`
6. `gunicorn app1:application -b localhost:8000 --timeout 90000 -w 17 --worker-class gevent`
7. `gunicorn app1:application -b localhost:8000 --timeout 90000 -w 17 --worker-class gthread`
8. `gunicorn app1:application -b localhost:8000 --timeout 90000 -w 17 --worker-class eventlet`